# HttpErrorResponse JSON.parse

Tags: json, angular, typescript, header, http-headers

I have a problem with a code. When I make the request of my array "carrito_arr" I get HttpErrorResponse in the browser console and it does not list the products of my online store.

It tells me that the error is in the attached code.

```
this._clienteService.obtener_cliente_guest(this.id, this.token).subscribe(
      response=>{
          
          this.user = response.data;
          
          localStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(this.user));

              //Validem que l'objecte està
            if(localStorage.getItem('user_data')){
              //Guardem
              this.user_lc = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data')|| '{}');

              console.log(this.user_lc);

              this._clienteService.obtener_carrito_cliente(this.user_lc._id, this.token).subscribe(
                response=>{
                  
                  this.carrito_arr = response.data;
                  this.calcular_carrito();
                }
              );
```

[image]

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error means an exception/issue exists on your back-end side. Try to debug in the back-end API, and see what is the exception hit.

Comment: This is the method i have in the backend: const obtener_carrito_cliente = async function (req, res){
    //Validem
    if(req.user){
        let id = req.params['id']; //Obtenim ID del client per fer consulta

        //Historial carrito client
        let carrito_cliente = await Carrito.find({cliente:id}).populate('producto');
       
        //Retornem la data al frontend
        res.status(500).send({data: carrito_cliente});

    }else{
        res.status(500).send({message: 'NoAccess'});
    }
}

Comment: the backend is all correct

Comment: what does your network log shows?